# Is it possible to use a String as the arguments for Files.move(source,target..) in Java?

Tags: java, string, file, move

Can you use strings in some way to define the source and target of files.move.

Heres the documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/move.html

Comment: What does the Javadoc for this class say? File doesn't have a move() method but `Files` does  ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is **no**: [`Files.move`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...%29) requires [`Path`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) objects. That said, you can use [`Paths.get(str)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html#get%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String...%29) to simply turn a `String` into a `Path`.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...%29), you can not use strings as arguments for Files.move .

What seems to be a better solution for you, is using the rename method on File. Something like this:

```
File file = new File("/path/to/file/to/be/moved");
boolean moved = file.renameTo("/new/path/for/the/file");
if(!moved)
  //Handle the error
```